# Dynamic params using remoteLink in Grails

Tags: grails

I want to make an Ajax call using remoteLink (with Prototype as the Javascript library) but I need one of the parameters being passed to be the value from a textfield.  Here's what I have so far in my GSP:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
...
<g:remoteLink action="addEmail" params="[email:???]">Add</g:remoteLink>
```

What do I put in place of ??? to get the remoteLink to send the value of the email textfield as a parameter?  Essentially, how do I reference/access the DOM within a Grails tag?

I tried putting

```
\$('email').value
```

in place of ??? but I got a "Could not parse script" error in my GSP.

Thanks

Comment: This question is old, starting from grails 3 using ajax related methods is deprected and <g:remoteLink> is not accepted as a default tag anymore without adding compile "org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1" in your build.gradle. see https://code-examples.net/en/q/1d62b9c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've need to do done something similar before and the following worked for me (yep, not especially elegant):

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
...
<g:javascript>
    var addEmail = function()
    {
        ${ remoteFunction (action:"addEmail", update:"update-element-id", params:"  'email=' +$('email').value  ") }
    };
</g:javascript>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addEmail();return false;">add email</a>
```

Extracted to a javascript function for clarity, and added some spaces inside the params to show the single quotes clearer.

Comment: This is better than the way I outlined; it allows you to switch from Prototype to something else without breaking the implementation.  Good suggestion, upvoted.

Comment: If you move the 
    var emailVal =  $('email').value;
line inside the function this works really well.  Can you please make the change in your answer and I'll accept this.  Thanks.

Comment: done. thx for up proflux, wish there was a more elegant way to get gsp and javascript to interact, guess its difficult with one being server and other client...

Answer (score 3):

`<g:remoteLink action="addEmail" params="${[email: some.groovy.to.get.your.email()]}">Add</g:remoteLink>`

Comment: This code is wrong, you can't have "some.groovy.to.get.your.email" because that code is rendered on the server before the page is displayed and the email field to be typed in. You need js code executed on the client AFTER the email field is populated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better solution for this.

Use before attribute in remoteLink tag to set a js variable containing your DOM things.

For example:
in js:

```
var MyJSClass = {
  setParams: function() {
    MyJSClass.dynamicParams = {email: $("#email").val(), myOtherField: anyJSLogicHere()}  
  }
}
```

in gsp:

```
<g:remoteLink action="addEmail" params="MyJSClass.dynamicParams" before="MyJSClass.setParams()">Add</g:remoteLink>
```

See the before code that is the js function that is executed before the request and sets the dynamicParams property that will be then used in the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using a button instead of a link this becomes trivial using the g:submitToRemote.  But, if it has to be a link, you can do something ugly like this:

The views/email/index.gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sample title</title>
    <g:javascript library="prototype" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <g:form name="theForm">
    Email: <g:textField name="emailAddr" />
    <!-- Here comes the ugly -->
    <a href="#" name="submit" 
       onclick="new Ajax.Updater('resp','${createLink(action:'addEmail')}',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:Form.serialize(document.theForm)});return false">
    Submit Form
    </a>
  </g:form>
  <div id="resp">
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The email controller:

```
class EmailController {

    def index = { }

    def addEmail = {

        if(params?.emailAddr) {
            render "${params.emailAddr}"
        }
        else {
            render "No Email Entered"
        }
    }
}
```

Couple things to note if you customize this:
* the first 'resp' argument to Ajax.Updater is the id of the div that you want to update
* in the Form.serialize(document.theForm) command, the 'theForm' needs to correspond with the name you assign the form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eduard's answer I deducted that Javascript code within the params attribute will be executed. So I tried the following and it worked:

```
<g:remoteLink action="addEmail" params="{email:\$('#email').val()}">Add</g:remoteLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to use remoteLink with Jquery, here is what worked for me.

```
<g:remoteLink action="${myBean.action}" params="[myParam: myBean.param]" update="updateDiv">
        My Awesome Link
</g:remoteLink>
```

simple and neat.

Comment: How this solve the problem to add to params a value of a text field that is inserted by user AFTER the page is rendered?

Comment: If i understand this correctly, you are looking to use a parameter(field) enter by user. You can use <g:submitToRemote> for that matter. I had the same issue, submitToRemote actually submits the whole form, so you can add a small form, and then the link/button can submit it.

<g:form action="show">
    Login: <input name="login" type="text" />
    <g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" />
</g:form>

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html

Comment: There is also a situation when you already have a form and a submit button, but also a remote link that needs to pass some parameters

Comment: I have used both for in the same form.. i have something like this.

`<g:form action="save">
    <g:remoteLink action="previous" class="btn" params="[myParam:myBean.param]">Previous</g:remoteLink>
    <g:submitToRemote class="btn btn-success" update="postSaveDiv" value="Save"/>
</g:form>`

This will work completely fine.